# How can I do a scrolling background animation like this in flutter web?

Tags: flutter

[link](https://essential.ravenbluethemes.com) for reference. I'm wanting to have a site I'm making have the logo in the foreground, an image in the background, that disappears as you scroll down the page. The stuff I'm trying to do is getting pretty complicated and convoluted (animated backgrounds, parallax, etc.). It seems like it should be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

give you an idea, this is the site is not quite parallax effect, the background image is fixed and carousel, and just make a scroll list in the foreground:

```
Stack(children:[
  ImageWidget/CarouselWidget,
  ListView(children:[
    //couple of Stack widget with transparent and color background
    Stack(children:[
      Container(color: Colors.transparent),
      Text('blablabla'), //may apply animation
    ]),
    Stack(children:[
      Container(color: Colors.blue),
      Text('blablabla'), //may apply animation
    ]),
    Stack(children:[
      Container(color: Colors.transparent),
      Text('blablabla'), //may apply animation
    ]),
    Stack(children:[
      Container(color: Colors.red),
      Text('blablabla'), //may apply animation
    ]),
  ])
])
```